# Custom fields in CiviGrants

Tags: civireport

I have just added some custom fields to grants but they dont show in reports - what have I missed? How do I get them to show up and be available in reports?

Cheers - Phil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you make the custom fields 'searchable'?

Because then they should pop up in your report. I tried it on the civi demo 
(http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/29?reset=1) and there they showed up.

Comment: I am on 4.5.2 (wordpress) and it doesn't seem to work - is this a recent feature addition?. They are ticked as searchable

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand exactly what your problem is: You want to add customfields to Grant and they should show up in your Civi CRM Grant report? if that is the case, then it works. Try the demo of civicrm in Joomla. I just did the same. http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/report/instance/28&reset=1         If the promblem is different, please describe what you want and what youve done so far.

Comment: All sorted now - I was getting a crash whilst trying to make the fields searchable. Now sorted. I suspect its just my lousy internet connection.